# SFINAE-test fails when checking for member function

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I tried to implement my own SFINAE test in order to determine the type of a template variable, in this case if it is a scalar or a vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename...>
using void_t = void;

template <typename, template <typename> class, typename = void_t<>>
struct detect : std::false_type {};

template <typename T, template <typename> class Op>
struct detect<T, Op, void_t<Op<T>>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
using toSize_t = decltype(std::declval<T>().size());

template <typename T>
using has_toSize = detect<T, toSize_t>;

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << "Hello World\n";
    std::vector<int> vec_a;
    std::vector<double> vec_b;
    double scal_a;
    int scal_b;
    std::cout << "scal_b is a vector: " << detect<int, has_toSize>{} << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Now, `int` definitely has no member function `size()`, but I still get a `true` instead of a `false` value. Why?

Comment: Did you mean to write `.. << has_toSize<int>{}`?

Comment: That works, but I took that example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7eae9c76232a2d20 , and there it was written as I wrote it.

Comment: But that example has no alias like your ``has_toSize``. If you would write ``detect<int, toSize_t>`` it woul be like your example. What you are doing is using ``detect`` twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression:

```
detect<int, has_toSize>{}
```

is quite weird.

Notice, that `has_toSize` is an alias. It is always a valid expression to write `has_toSize<T>` where `T` is an arbitrary type. As a result `detect` detects that `Op<T>`, where `Op` is `has_toSize`, is a valid expression. So, the output is `true`.

The right way to use `detect` is:

```
std::cout << has_toSize<int>{} << std::endl;
                       ^^^^^
                     check type
```

This means, that you check whether a type (`int` in this particular case) has `size()` member function.

Answer (score 1):

In C++17 you could make use of `is_detected`.  This hides all the SFINAE in a nice metafunction.  The invocation is similar to the other answer.

```
#include <experimental/type_traits>

template < typename T >
using toSize_t = decltype(std::declval<T>().size());

template < typename T >
using has_toSize = std::experimental::is_detected< toSize_t, T >;

int main()
{
  static_assert( has_toSize<int>::value == false );
}
```